# get a record with only top 10 records in nested table entity framework core

Tags: lambda, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have a table (tblA) with couple of columns that one of them is a collection of another table (tblB).
I want get a record from tblA with only top 10 records of tblB.

how can achieve this.

I use this code but I didn`t get answer :

```
var fetchData = 
               tblA.GetAll()
               .Include(x=>x.tblB.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Timestamp).Take(10))
               .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
```

Comment: [Filtered Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) has been added in EF Core 5.0, so it can't be used in 3.1 (if the tag is correct).

Comment: yes you are right. I mean EF Core 5.0

Comment: What doesn't work? Exception? No data? More data than expected?

Comment: No. I don`t know. it work without error or exception. but brings me back all records on tblB

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

but I think it`s more a Trick than Solution.
but it answered me :

first of all I`ve got all tblA data with my filter and then I create an object of tblB (objTblB) and got top 10 related rows.
finally replace tblB collection in tblA with that object

```
var fetchData = tblA.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
var objTblB = fetchData.tblB.OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp).Take(10).ToList();
fetchData.tblB = objTblB;
```